# don't get response retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

When I download the image using the browser, I get the answer.

I use the same server to download the image using Android and Retrofit2, the image is well uplode and I see the result of processing in the terminal, but I get nothing in the application.

```
resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            // Response Success or Fail
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body().getResult().equals("success")) {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_upload_success, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("onResponse", "File Uploaded Successfully");
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_upload_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("onResponse", " Something went wrong");
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_upload_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("onResponse", " Something went wrong");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("onFailure", t.getMessage());
            Log.e("onFailure", Arrays.toString(t.getStackTrace()));
        }
    });
```

Here are the errors

```
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220), 
retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37), 
retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyC onverter.java:25), retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116),
retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211), 
retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106), 
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133), 
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32), 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113),
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588),
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

The result class:

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private String result;

    /**
     * @return The result
     */
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param result The result
     */
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Comment: post result class

Comment: I add the result class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been through the same error, the main issue

the response which you are getting from the API is in an array format

But you are trying to get in object format.

Check your Response Model.

Comment: Yes, the response is in an array format but I'm just sending the 1st element. The code of Nodejs `res.send(result[0]) `

Comment: I change type of result from String to ArrayList in Result Class
ThanK you @zuhad

Comment: Welcome brother :)